# From end to start how to get everything from the 5th occurence of "-"?

Tags: c#, .net, substring

I have this string:
abc-8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563-a7346703098b

I want to go through this string starting from the end and grab everything till the 5th occurence of the "-" sign.

how do I substring this string to only show (has to be through the procedure described above): -8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563-a7346703098b

Comment: How would "grab[bing] everything till the 5th occurence of `-`" give you `-8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563-a7346703098b` and not `abc-8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563`?

Comment: Your problem statement and expected output contradict each other.  Please clarify.

Comment: I feel like this is a homework question, given that it is an extremely simple problem asked to be completed in the most convoluted way to try to get someone to not just use `var substr = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('-'));`...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen _"... through this string **starting from the end**"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your string rules, I would do a simple split :

```
var text = "abc-8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563-a7346703098b";
var split = text.split('-');
if (split.Lenght <= 5)
   return text;
return string.Join('-', split.Skip(split.Lenght - 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define handy extension method if that's common use case:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string GetSubstringFromReversedOccurence(this string @this,
        char @char,
        int occurence)
    {
        var indexes = new List<int>();
        var idx = 0;

        while ((idx = @this.IndexOf(@char, idx + 1)) > 0)
        {
            indexes.Add(idx);
        }

        if (occurence > indexes.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not enough occurences of character");
        }

        var desiredIndex = indexes[indexes.Count - occurence];

        return @this.Substring(desiredIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use a regex replacement with a capture group:

```
var text = "abc-8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563-a7346703098b";
var pattern = @"([^-]+(?:-[^-]+){4}).*";
var output = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1"); 
Console.WriteLine(output);  // abc-8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563
```

If we can rely on the input always having 6 hyphen separated components, we could also use this version:

```
var text = "abc-8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563-a7346703098b";
var pattern = @"-[^-]+$";
var output = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, ""); 
Console.WriteLine(output);  // abc-8479fe75-82rb5-45g00-b563
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the most performant

```
public string GetSubString(string text)
{
    var count = 0;
    for (int i = text.Length-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (text[i] == '-') count++;
        if (count == 5) return text.Substring(i);
    }
    return null;
}
```